# How to get values of all EditText inside a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to get all the values of all the EditText elements that are present inside my ListView.
This is my code :

```
final ListView editorList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.editorList);
        final EditorAdapter adapter = new EditorAdapter(context, data);
        editorList.setAdapter(adapter);


        Button commitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.commit_button);
        commitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                    //System.out.println("Size of List : " + editorList.getChildCount());
                    for(int i =0;i< data.size() ;i++){
                        System.out.println("Size of List : " + data.size());

                        EditText value = adapter.getItem(i);
                        String propertyValue = value.getText().toString();
                        System.out.println("PropertyValue : " + propertyValue);


                    }
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

This is my Adapter class :

```
package in.omerjerk.preferenceseditor;


public class EditorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data;
EditText[] mHolders;

public EditorAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data){

    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    System.out.println("No . of items in nodes"+data.size());
    mHolders = new EditText[data.size()];

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public EditText getItem(int pos) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mHolders[pos];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return pos;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null){
        System.out.println("CONVERT VIEW IS NULL");
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_edit_string,null,false);
        holder.editPropertyValue = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.propertyValue);
        holder.propertyName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.propertyName);

        holder.propertyName.setText(data.get(position).get("propertyName"));
        holder.editPropertyValue.setText(data.get(position).get("propertyName"));
        convertView.setTag(holder);



    }else{
        System.out.println("CONVERT VIEW NOT NULL");
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.propertyName.setText(data.get(position).get("propertyName"));
        holder.editPropertyValue.setText(data.get(position).get("propertyName"));
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        mHolders[position] = new EditText(context);
        mHolders[position] = holder.editPropertyValue;
    }

    return convertView;
}

}
```

I'm getting strange error in my output. The mHolders array only contain upto 6-7 elements and these elements are repeated in the entire array. I'm able to get the values of EditText but the error is not correct.

Comment: post XML from layout as well, thanks

Comment: Post EditorAdapter as well

Comment: You are creating a new `View` every time `getView` is called which is very bad and wrong. And also your code does not follow `ViewHolder` pattern. Please correct your adapter first. Lot of tutorials are available on ths topic, http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Comment: the values that you're trying to get, are on the adapter or are entered by the user?

Comment: @AlfredoCavalcanti Those are created by the java code but they can be edited by the user.

Comment: omer jerk! have you not checked my answer? @omerjerk

Answer (score 12):

This is not going to work the way you'd expect. Views are recycled when using an `Adapter`. This means that there are only as many inflated views as there are visible on screen (plus a couple). So, if you're trying to iterate over all of the children, you will find that any offscreen items will return null.

The proper way to do this is to use a `Collection` of objects that **represent** the values of the `EditText` as your `Adapter` data. This way, in `getView` you simply check the value of the object at that position, and then call `setText()` on the view. When you want to get all values, you create a method like `getItems()` in the `Adapter`, and iterate over that `Collection`.

If you post the relevant parts of the `Adapter` code, I can show you exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 10):

Try this way and modify as per your requirement. I have used ArrayList of HashMap instead of NodeList

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lst"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/getAllValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Get All Value"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**row_edit_string.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/propertyName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editPropertyValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.MyTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView lst;
    private Button getAllValue;
    private EditorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lst=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lst);
        getAllValue=(Button)findViewById(R.id.getAllValue);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String,String> row1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        row1.put("name","FirstName");
        row1.put("value","FirstValue");
        data.add(row1);
        HashMap<String,String> row2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        row2.put("name","SecondName");
        row2.put("value","SecondValue");
        data.add(row2);
        HashMap<String,String> row3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        row3.put("name","ThirdName");
        row3.put("value","ThirdValue");
        data.add(row3);
        HashMap<String,String> row4 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        row4.put("name","FourthName");
        row4.put("value","FourthValue");
        data.add(row4);
        HashMap<String,String> row5 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        row5.put("name","FifthName");
        row5.put("value","FifthValue");
        data.add(row5);
        adapter = new EditorAdapter(this,data);
        lst.setAdapter(adapter);

        getAllValue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String allValues="";
                ArrayList<String> valueList = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
                    allValues +=((HashMap<String,String>)adapter.getItem(i)).get("value")+ ",";
                    valueList.add(((HashMap<String,String>)adapter.getItem(i)).get("value"));
                }
                // use this valueList as per ur requirement
                allValues = allValues.substring(0,allValues.length()-1);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,allValues,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

    }

}


    class EditorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data;

    public EditorAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data){

        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return data.get(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_edit_string,null,false);
            holder.editPropertyValue = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editPropertyValue);
            holder.propertyName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.propertyName);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.propertyName.setText(data.get(position).get("name"));
        holder.editPropertyValue.setText(data.get(position).get("value"));

        convertView.setTag(holder);
        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        EditText editPropertyValue;
        TextView propertyName;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: By going this way I don't think the changes made in the `EditText` fields done by the user will be reflected in the `getAllValue.setOnClickListener()`

Comment: @omerjerk once a change is made in the edittext you will have to reflect them somewhere, or in the same list that you use in the adapter. this is because, every time you scroll if the values are not stored correctly, you will fill your edittext with the old values only. That way everytime a change is made by the user, it would never be reflected, cz its never retained at all

Answer (score 2):

I am right now copying your question and giving you a fast solution. Keep in mind that your code is not optimized and that my code is not optimized as well. Moreover, I just wrote my code, it has not even been tested syntactically.

The idea is to keep track of each of the EditText's values. I used a HashMap.

This is your new Adapter class :

```
public class EditorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    NodeList nodes;
    int sizeOfList;

    //here is the hashmap and its getter I talked about upstairs
    HashMap<Integer, String> mValues = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    public HashMap<Integer, String> getValues() {
        return mValues;
    }
    public EditorAdapter(Context context, NodeList nodes, int sizeOfList){

        this.context = context;
        this.nodes = nodes;
        this.sizeOfList = sizeOfList;
        System.out.println("No . of items in nodes"+nodes.getLength());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return sizeOfList;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //if one of the convertView is reused (but in ur case discarded) let me update the value for that position in case changed
        if(convertView!=null && nodes.item(position).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            mValues.put((Integer) convertView.getTag(), ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.propertyValue)).getText().toString());
        }
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = new View(context);
        Node node = nodes.item(position);

        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) { 
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_edit_string, null);
            //set the tag of this view to the position
            rowView.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
            TextView propertyName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.propertyName);
            Element child = (Element) node;
            propertyName.setText(child.getAttribute("name"));
            EditText editPropertyValue = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.propertyValue);
            if(position == 1){
                editPropertyValue.requestFocus();
            }
            if(node.getNodeName().equals("string")){

                editPropertyValue.setText(child.getTextContent());
            } else {
                editPropertyValue.setText(child.getAttribute("value"));
            }
        }

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

---

Now let us update your onClick. The only problem here is that mValues is not sufficient because the hashmap only guarantees values of discarded/reused convertViews but not values of EditTexts already on the screen.

```
    final ListView editorList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.editorList);
    final EditorAdapter mAdapter = new EditorAdapter(context, nodes, sizeOfList);
    editorList.setAdapter(mAdapter);


Button commitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.commit_button);
commitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            //I am getting the hashmap
            HashMap<Integer, String> mValues = mAdapter.getValues();
            for(int i=0;i<editorList.getChildCount() ;i++) {
                View layout = editorList.getChildAt(i);
                //I am checking if any of the visible children is an EditText and updating its value in the HashMap
                if(layout.getTag()!=null && layout.getTag() instanceof Integer) {
                    mValues.put((Integer) layout.getTag(), ((TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.propertyValue)).getText().toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //now if you want the Text of the EditText on position `2` (for example) Use:
        String valueAtPosition_2 = mValues.get(position);
        if(valueAtPosition_2 == null) {
            //this means the view at position two is not really an EditText and the node at position 2 is not of type Node.ELEMENT_NODE
        }
        else {
            //here is your value!
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way hope this helps you

```
commitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try{
                    //System.out.println("Size of List : " + editorList.getChildCount());
                    for(int i =0;i<editorList.getChildCount() ;i++){
                        Node node = nodes.item(i);
                         Element child = (Element) node;
                        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) { 

                            if(node.getNodeName().equals("string")){
                                System.out.println("TextContent : "+child.getTextContent());
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("AttributeValue : "+child.getAttribute("value"));
                            }
                        }




                    }
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the scroll view with container that holds your list items as children. on the click listener you can iterate through all the children and find out the values that are entered in the edittext. If really don't need the listview you can try something like this.