# How I set this List with Hashmap Datatype to a list view?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a List with hash map data type and i want to set it to a custom layout so please guys help me. i m so frustrated.

```html
    public void Showsongs(List<HashMap<String, String>> songs)
{
    ...//What?
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: use base-adapter or array-adapter to custom layout.

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209905/how-to-get-values-of-all-edittext-inside-a-listview/19311882#19311882

Comment: i know to use base-adapter but how? @Yugesh

Comment: @XäiñUlAbideen Refer this [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/558903/java/java/Sorting-List-Hash-Map).if not possible use **Hash-map Array-list** to implement.

Comment: http://www.pcsalt.com/android/listview-using-baseadapter-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use simpleadapter:
ex.

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, maps, R.layout.yourlayoutname, from, to)
```